# Spider-Woman (616) sticks to walls with an adhesive fluid excreted from her pores. Is there a comic-source for this?

Tags: marvel, comics

According to [Comic Vine](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/spider-woman/4005-1453/)/[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Woman_(Jessica_Drew)), Spider-Woman (616) sticks to walls with a fluid excreted from her pores. Is there a comic source for this?

Other wikis indicate her ability is actually based in electrostatic cling or the enhancement of inter-atomic forces, but these explanations are essentially copied over from various Spider-Man handbooks about Peter Parker's ability to wall crawl. I'm fairly certain that, therefore, such explanations aren't canonical to Spider-Woman. I'd accept them if I hadn't come across such an odd "fluid" based explanation of her abilities.

Comment: https://i2.wp.com/www.adventuresinpoortaste.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/soman2.png?w=1200

Answer (score 6):

This information is confirmed in multiple locations, not least in the 1992 [Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe Master Edition Vol. 1 #8](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_Master_Edition_Vol_1_8) where we learn that [Spider-Woman (*Jessica Drew*)](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Jessica_Drew_(Earth-616)) can exude adhesive material from her palms and soles (latterly she learns to cast them like Spider-Man's web shooters).

[image]

The wikis may be confusing her *web-crawling* ability with [Spider-Woman II (*Julia Carpenter*)](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Julia_Carpenter_(Earth-616)) who's described as having the ability to project a psionic field from her fingers that allows her to adhere to surfaces.

[image]